# How to tell parent class an element has changed in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add an element from a list called "Others" to a list called "Favorites" and vice-versa once I click the "add to favorite" button, I am really new to reactJS and I am solving this purely for practicing purposes.

What I am trying to do is creating a handleClick that toggles the state of a single contact from "Other" to "Favorite" and vice-versa, this is done on the "User" component, meanwhile the caller of this is the "Users" component, however I am not finding a way to tell the "Users" component that a "User" has changed and should switchLists, this is my code right now.

Users

```
class Users extends Component{
    render(){
            this.props.users.sort(function(a,b){
                if(a.name > b.name){
                    return 1;
                }else{
                    return -1;
                }
            })
            return( 
                <div>
                <h1>Favorites</h1>
                <div>{this.props.users.map(user => <User user={user}
                favList = {true}
                key={user.id}/>)}</div>
                <h1>Others</h1>
                <div>{this.props.users.map(user => <User user={user}
                    favList = {false}
                    key={user.id}/>)}</div>
                </div>
            )   




    }
}
```

User

```
class User extends Component{
    StyleCompleted(){
        return {
            fontSize: '20px',


        }
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {isToggleOn: this.props.user.isFavorite
        };

        // Este enlace es necesario para hacer que `this` funcione en el callback
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {

    this.setState(state => ({
        isToggleOn: !state.isToggleOn
    }));
    }

    render(){

        const {user} = this.props;
        const {favList} = this.props;
        if (favList==this.state.isToggleOn)
        return (
            <div > 
                <img src={UserImage} alt="userPic"/>
                {user.name} - 
                {user.companyName}
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    <Star star={
                        this.state.isToggleOn ? 
                        true : false
                    }/>
                </button>

            </div>
            )
        else
            return (<h1>Element changes but is not added</h1>)

    }
}
```

Star

```
class Star extends Component{


    render(){
        const {star} = this.props;

        return (
            <img src={
                star ? starTrue : starFalse
            } alt="star"/>
        )
    }
}
```

The expected result when I click an element should be to remove it from the current list and add it to the other list, the actual result is just a change on the current node/element

Answer (score 0):

You need to elevate your click handler to the parent function and manage state there instead of at the individual user level. You could pass down a prop from parent to child to pass this information back and forth while managing state in the child. However, this is extremely bad practice as it create the possibility of two sources of truth.